# How to get location of moving a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiimageview, sigabrt

In `touchesBegan` I have this, and some other irrelevant code. :

```
CGPoint center;
center = [[self.squareOne.layer presentationLayer] center];
```

`squareOne` uses a block-based `UIView animation` to move. The animation code:

```
self.squareOne.center = position;
self.squareOne.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((a + 1) * M_1_PI);
```

If it really matter this is what `position` is:

```
position.x = self.widthOfScreen/8 + self.widthOfScreen;
position.y = y;
//y is any number between 0 and the height of the screen
```

But when I click the screen, I get the dreaded: `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. (I say the other code in `touchesBegan` is irrelevant because those 2 lines of code are the problem. Pretty much the rest are just if-statements which will ultimately just make `squareOne` become hidden). I am asking how I can get the location of a `UIImageView` mid-animation when I click the screen. It doesn't matter if you get the center, I just want to know how to get a relative value of `squareOne`'s position while it's moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that there is no center on a presentation layer, but you can get a frame. Try this...

```
 CALayer *layer = self.squareOne.layer;
 CGRect frame = [[layer presentationLayer] frame];
 CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMaxY(frame));
```

Hopefully that helps.